# eventListener not catching keypress event with Javascript

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, dom-events

I've written some code to check if a user launches a search on Google (clicking on the Search button or typing Enter).

My code works fine (it's a Firefox extension) except I can't get the code of the key pressed for an unknow reason.

my code :

```
window.addEventListener("submit", function() { myExtension_with_click.init(); }, false);
window.addEventListener("keypress", function() { myExtension_with_keypress.init(); }, false);

var myExtension_with_click = {
    init: function() {          
         alert("This works");
    }
}

var myExtension_with_keypress = {
    init: function() {
             alert("This works")
             if (window.event.keyCode == 13) {
                 // This doesn't work
                 alert("This doesn't work");
             }
    }
}
```

Comment: pass parameter as event as define the function as function(event) and in the if condition(event.keyCode==13) it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple solution is to use the event "change" in the event listener !

Answer (score 1):

try this it works

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
    window.addEventListener("submit", function() { myExtension_with_click.init(); }, false);
    window.addEventListener("keypress", function(event) { myExtension_with_keypress.init(event); }, false);

    var myExtension_with_click = {
        init: function() {          
             alert("This works");
        }
    }

    var myExtension_with_keypress = {
        init: function(event) {
                 //alert("This works")
                 if (event.keyCode == 13) {
                     // This doesn't work
                     alert("This doesn't work");
                 }
        }
    }

</script>
</head>
<body>
    <input />
</body>
```

Comment: I've tested your solution and unfortunately it doesn't work perfectly : when I type "Enter" after writing a keyword in the search form the alert isn't displayed, the alert is only displayed if the focus isn't on the search form (when I click on a part of the page and then type "Enter").

Comment: @Brune you mean that when user enter word like 'Enter' then it will display the message. actually what you want? you want keycode or specifically word

Comment: I want the Javascript alert to be displayed when a user puts a keyword in the form and then types "Enter" to launch the search. What I mean is that your code only works when the focus isn't in the search form. I mean the problem with my original code is that it only detects a Google search when a user clicks on the Search button not when a user launches a search with Enter.